# AMDGPU-Pro 18.20 for Ubuntu 18.04, Raven ridge supported?

Tags: 18.04, amdgpu-pro

Does the AMDGPU-Pro 18.20 early preview support Raven Ridge? I can't tell from the product support list if "RX Vega Series Graphics" also includes Raven Ridge or only discrete cards.

link to driver:
https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-18.20-Early-Preview-Release-Notes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually, already the AMDGPU-Pro 18.10 supports Raven Ridge. Tried both, and opencl 18.10 works on Raven Ridge, while 18.20 does not. Tested platform was R7 2400G on an Gigabyte GA-AB350M-DS3H board (which is in fact a x370 board). with latest BIOS.